# masking/redirecting a folder to querystring on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a single page in Wordpress that has lookups to a sql server and presents different content based on the querystring.
For instance, the URL I use is https://some-server.com/dynamic-page/?stem=name-of-content-to-be-looked-up

When I access the page and change the querystring, the content changes.  Perfect.

Now, I do not want the querystring to be exposed to the end user, so I am attempting to use mod_rewrite such as this:

```
RewriteRule ^ds/(.*) /dynamic-page/?stem=$1 [PT]
```

The idea being that the URL to the end user would look like https://some-server.com/ds/name-of-content-to-be-looked-up

When I use a 301 redirect, it works great.  When I use the internal redirect, it 404's.  I have tried several different flags on the end, but all fail with a 404.

Has anyone ever tried this and done it successfully?  Care to share some ideas?

I have tried the following, plus more, none work:

```
RewriteRule ^ds/(.*) /dynamic-page/?stem=$1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^ds/(.*) /dynamic-page/?stem=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ds/(.*) /dynamic-page/?stem=$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^ds/(.*) /dynamic-page?stem=$1 [QSA,NS,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ds/
RewriteRule ^ds/(.*) /index.php/dynamic-page?stem=$1 [PT]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.  Instead of doing it in apache redirect, I was able to add some filters into my wordpress functions.php file:

```
function setup_filter_query_vars($query_vars)
{
    $query_vars[] = 'stem';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'setup_filter_query_vars' );


function setup_filter_rewrites()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('ds/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?stem=$matches[1]&pagename=dynamic-page&', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'setup_filter_rewrites' );
```

After that, I had to reference the querystring variable in a slightly different fashion from within the page.  I had to change the standard "$_GET["stem"];" to "get_query_var( 'stem', 1 );"

I hope this helps someone else.